# Insertar imágenes de una lista de SharePoint a una app de Python

Tags: python, sharepoint

Hola como estoy desarrollando una app en Python relacionada con Desktop Alerts estas deben mostrar imagenes de una campaña que estan alojadas en un SharePoint como implemento para que esas imagenes dentro de un SharePoint puedan verse dentro de mi App?

Este es el codigo que estoy implementando solo faltarian esas imagenes del SharePoint.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from plyer import notification

#notification.notify(
    #title='SOPORTE EC',
    #message='Recuerda si tú o un cliente necesitan soporte técnico escribe a #soporteec, se generará un ticket y tu atención será inmediata.',
    #app_icon="icon.ico",
    #timeout=10,
#)
def change_image():
    images = ["General 1.png", "General 2.png", "General 3.png"]
    image_path = random.choice(images)
    image = tk.PhotoImage(file=image_path)
    label.config(image=image)
    label.image = image
    root.after(10000, change_image)
def hide_app():
    root.iconify()  # Ocultar la ventana de la aplicación
    root.after(10000, show_app)  # Llamar a show_app después de 20 segundos
def show_app():
    root.deiconify()  # Mostrar la ventana de la aplicación
    root.after(10000, hide_app) 

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
root.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

change_image()
show_app()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Se puede descargar las imagenes o verlas desde el navegador? Pregunto por que si existe la posibilidad de algo de eso, se podría intentar acceder a esa url, descargar la imagen en memoria y así cargarla en tkinter.

Comment: Si se pueden ver y descargar, como puedo implementarlo en tkinter?

Comment: Cabe recalcar que no es solo una imagen son varias imagenes dentro de una carpeta alojada en SharePoint

Comment: Depende de como funcione la pagina que provee la imagen (no se que es un SharePoint) (por ejemplo, quizá requiere un token o tiene un captcha), pero podrías probar con utilizar el modulo de terceros request, hacer request.get(url_imagen). Eso devuelve un objeto con los datos de la pagina en cuestión. Si la pagina es solo una imagen, es posible que puedas obtener la imagen en forma de bytes con el atributo content. Todo esto depende de como funcione un sharepoint, así que prefiero esperar a que me confirmes si lo antes dicho funciona, e investigar más sobre eso, antes de decirte como cargar.

Comment: Busca algo del estilo "como cargar una imagen a partir de una url en tkinter". En ingles, probablemente consigas más resultados.